# How to determine a .tib extension from acronis image file type

Tags: file-format, acronis-trueimage

I have windows 7 64 bit professional OS in my laptop.Recently I have created a backup of my hard drive with acronis(http://www.acronis.com/en-us/) image creator. Now I would like to find the resultant file *pcbackup.tib*(my backup file name) format, **is it FAT32 or NTFS**.

Comment: The .tib file format is a proprietary design by Acronis. From my understanding of how image backups work, the contents of the file is going to be mostly RAW data, which means that there isn't really a filesystem format present in the file. If there is, I would assume that it would be the same format that the original drive was in order to increase the probability of a seamless restore.

Comment: NOTE: A serious issue in using any backup application is whether the company (and underlying format) will be retrieval in the time frame you need it.  I have personally been disappointed in this respect.

Comment: My only issue ever with acronis has been if the restore can't correctly access the network archive. Throwing the tib onto a removable drive has always got the machine back up & running in short order. Lost 3 boot drives here this year, no data loss.

Comment: Mount the drive using in any supported version of Acronis.